# Dell Inspiron 3541 graphic driver issue

Tags: windows-8, laptop, drivers, graphics-card

Recently I bought Dell Inspiron 3541. It had Ubuntu as an OS and I installed Windows 8. I have had a hard time finding drivers since the Dell website doesn't have drivers for this model laptop of windows 8 (Only for windows 7 and 8.1). This laptop has 2GB AMD Radeon Graphics.

I managed to get all the drivers, except the graphics driver. I have installed Radeon 8500M series graphics driver but the graphics of the laptop stays as Microsoft Basic display. I tried couple of different drivers and None seem to work. If I go to *Device manager* -> *Display adapter*, I can see both Radeon graphics and Microsoft basic display. And if go to *dxdiag (DirectX diagnostic tool)*, it shows graphics is *Microsoft basic display 256 Mb*.

How can I change the graphics adapter to Radeon so that I can us the 2GB? Is there a way to switch the graphics?

Comment: *...dell site doesn't have drivers for this model laptop of windows 8 (Only for windows 7 and 8.1)* Any reason to not go to 8.1?

Comment: @Dave i've been trying to update.But it seems to be that the download doesnt go beyond 2%.

Comment: Hmmm, finding out why you are not being able to update should warrant investigation I think; it *may* indicate that you will get other issues in the future!

Comment: @Dave Unlike you think I have a proper copy of the OS :) I guess its the slow internet connection that causing the trouble.

Comment: Sounds like your actual question is the reason you cannot upgrade to 8.1.  Of course most if not all device drivers meant for 8.0 will work for 8.1 except for display drivers.  You still need to go to 8.1 if you want future windows updates because 8.0 will slowly not get certain updates.

Comment: @Ramhound but I got a windows 8 driver graphics driver . Like i said its intalled too.

Comment: The standard AMD display driver for your card should be enough.  have you installed that?

Comment: @Ramhound I installed it.It shows in device manager. But the used one is microsoft basic display.

Comment: I'm a little lost when you say "you think I have a proper copy of the OS". If the OS isn't proper, then I suggest you get a genuine version as this could be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

try to update the windows driver, by going to **device manager** and under **display adaptors** find your default system driver, rick click and choose **update driver software** and  if the windows reports that the **driver is up to date**, then **uninstall the radon 8500M driver** by following these steps,

Start/search ->type **devmgmt.msc** and press enter. In Device manager window, expand Display Adaptors and find your installed graphics driver, rick click and choose Uninstall. Also choose **delete driver software** for the device and press ok. Now install radon 8500M driver and **restart** your machine.

Comment: delete both amd and microsoft basic display adapter?

Comment: No, only AMD adapter